# Case insensitive comparison of constant strings

Tags: c, string, case-insensitive

I'm trying to use this function to compare two strings, case insensitively.

```
int strcasecmp(const char *x1, const char *x2);
```

I have the copy piece correct, yet the case sensitive portion is giving me some trouble as const is a constant, thus read only, making these fail:

```
*x1 = (tolower(*x1)); // toupper would suffice as well, I just chose tolower
*x2 = (tolower(*x2)); // likewise here
```

Both chars must remain `const`, otherwise I think this would work...
So my question: is there a way to ignore capitalization while keeping the `char`-strings `const`?

Comment: so why don't you just use a temp value to store (tolower(*x))?

Comment: Copy the data into a non-const char array, converting all chars to lowercase.

Comment: @Marcus I am not permitted to change *x1 or *x2 to anything other than a const char

Comment: no, you don't have to change neither *x1 nor *x2, just use tmp1 and tmp2 to do that.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry. I understand now. Thank you for your help- much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a temporary char variable:

```
char c1 = tolower(*x1);
char c2 = tolower(*x2);

if (c1 == c2)
 ...
```

Comment: It's the same problem though, as you can't assign anything to a read only location (*x1 & *x2).

Comment: They're being assigned to local variables. How is that read only?

Comment: @user1513475: That code is assigning to local non-const `char` variables `c1` and `c2`.  No violation of constness there.

Comment: One advantage of assigning to the local variables is that you can simply return the difference without re-evaluating the lower case values.  The only bit to watch is signed-ness; you might be better off using `int` instead of `char` for the local variables to avoid those problems.  You might also be getting warnings about passing signed char to the macros (possibly about using signed char to index an array).

Comment: Yes, you all are right. I was looking at the same compile error from before.

Answer (score 2):

Sure - you can compare the results of `tolower` right in the `if` statement:

```
while (*x1 && *x2 && tolower(*x1) == tolower(*x2)) {
    x1++;
    x2++;
}
return tolower(*x1)-tolower(*x2);
```

Comment: You don't normally return 0 when the characters are different

Comment: Minor: Could simplify to `*x1 && tolower(*x1) == tolower(*x2)`.